# Why can't I select multiple objects?

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I am currently unable to select more than one object at a time for some reason. I have object mode selected. I then use shift + LMB (mouse buttons swapped from Blender 2.78 default). But the select just moves to which ever object I select and deselects any object I had already selected. I also tried box select, which now selects nothing. I have applied transformations as I know unapplied transformations can make things screwey. It was working just fine earlier. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: hmm, I switched the theme to ScienceLab. Selection appearance is different! Anyone know how mod the theme to make selection appear properly?

Answer (score 4):

OK the problem was the theme. With ScienceLab theme the colour of selected and unselected objects is too similar for my eyes. Had to modify the theme.

Comment: Good to know, thx

Answer (score 0):

In the outliner if you accidentally type while renaming (without having renaming properly started) you can mess up the selection enabled flags.

Type **'a'** to 'select all' (in the outliner) and then **'s'** to re-enable the selection enabled icons (arrows between eye and camera).